# Stop an already running cron job

Tags: cron

I have a PHP script on server that sends newsletter emails to my site users using a cron job. The users list is approximately 55,000 and takes nine hours.

Is there any way to stop it (urgently)?

Comment: bg; to get the processes runing, kill to it

Comment: Please describe how do i kill this?

Comment: `ps -e` will give you the list of process, and `kill processid` (processid is a number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.admin/2006-09/msg00132.html

http://unix.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/shellscript-l/how-to-kill-the-cronjob-which-is-running-currently-477250

You need to get the PID of your running cron job and then perform simple kill command.

Comment: Cron job script file is on host server. I have cPanel only. how do i check all processes by ps -e command?

Comment: If you don't have any kind of SSH access to command terminal, you can't do that.

Comment: You may use the [`system`](http://php.net/system) command to exec something from your php script and see the output.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest allowing the use of system(), exec(), passthru(), etc. Its a security issue.

If you do have a control panel, there has to be a way to manage the cron jobs, and I believe with most of them you also have the ability to launch an SSH session. You could use this method to stop/start the running process.

Last but not least, if you can't stop it yourself, contact your host.

Answer (score 2):

someone already wrote u the answer,

try:

1. ps -e | grep "php name file"

   the above command will display you the process id, so:
2. kill - 9 'process ID'

   : )

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out the specific cron job you want to not run. Switch to the user that controls the task, export your editor of choice into the environment, then use crontab -l:

```
$ su - root
...
# EDITOR=vi; export EDITOR
# crontab -l
```

If you are using cPanel. GO to Advance section of the Corn Job and click the Delete button.

If the delete button is not there, switch cPanel skin to 'X' to view the Delete button.

Comment: Either you didn't read the question or you failed to understand it. The OP is asking how to stop an already running cron job, not how to edit it.